# Unable to load the Google map in Android Eclipse

Tags: android, api

I am using Google map in my app but getting the below error while run this

Authorization failure.

07-02 12:44:45.559: E/Google Maps Android API(2447): Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.
07-02 12:44:45.563: E/Google Maps Android API(2447): In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
07-02 12:44:45.563: E/Google Maps Android API(2447): Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
07-02 12:44:45.563: E/Google Maps Android API(2447): Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
07-02 12:44:45.563: E/Google Maps Android API(2447):    API Key: AIzaSyCwWioLbwEVhUGFf6BN-prF984pFcfKCOw
07-02 12:44:45.563: E/Google Maps Android API(2447):    Android Application (;): 95:31:6E:43:EB:62:90:0D:4E:48:0D:94:FC:27:22:88:79:1A:06:3C;com.scanchex.ui

Regards,
Pranav

Comment: did you generate the api key correctly ??

Answer (score 0):

To integrate google maps please follow https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

I think you did not get any key . You have to generate a cert for debug mode https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#debugmode

Answer (score 0):

**First of configure SHA1** key on your https://console.developers.google.com/

generate sha1 using following ( Every computer have own sha1 key so if you change your pc then you re-configure sha1 key ):

```
 C:\Users\admin\.android>keytool -list -v -keystore debug.keystore
```

Copy it and put on your google application account like sha1key;packagename  and generate api-key from the google developer console . copy this api-key.

**Check following permission are taken or not :**

```
<permission
   android:name="com.javapapers.currentlocationinmap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.javapapers.currentlocationinmap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Set meta-data and api-key :**

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="api-key from the google developer console" />
```

**Copy and paste following activity_map.xml file :**

```
  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rl_raw_header">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/googleMap"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/latlongLocation" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/latlongLocation"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#ff058fff"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Copy paste following Map_Activity :**

```
 public class Map_Activity extends FragmentActivity implements  LocationListener {

   GoogleMap googleMap;
   ImageView img_chat_back;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //show error dialog if GoolglePlayServices not available
    if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
        finish();
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);


    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment =
            (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap);
    googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
    if (location != null) {
        onLocationChanged(location);
    }

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    TextView locationTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latlongLocation);
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
    locationTv.setText("Latitude:" + latitude + ", Longitude:" + longitude);
}

private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status) {
        return true;
    } else {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 0).show();
        return false;
      }
    }
 }
```

Hopes its working fine for you and also helpful to others.